# How to get the distinct count in a Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the distinct count of products per order_number. I managed to get the total_product count (thanks to the help of another SO user), but I can't figure out the distinct count.

This is what I have:

```
data['total_productcount'] = data.groupby(['order_number'])['order_number'].transform('size')
```

And it gives:

```
order_number          product_id      total_productcount   
171-1046037-0511522   4260179734731   5                    
171-1046037-0511522   4054673034394   5                   
171-1046037-0511522   4054673001235   5                   
171-1046037-0511522   4054673005752   5                    
171-1046037-0511522   5011385960075   5                    
171-1046037-0511522   5011385960075   5
```

This is the dataframe, that I would like to generate (including: distict_productcount)

```
order_number          product_id      total_productcount   distict_productcount
171-1046037-0511522   4260179734731   5                    1
171-1046037-0511522   4054673034394   5                    1
171-1046037-0511522   4054673001235   5                    1
171-1046037-0511522   4054673005752   5                    1
171-1046037-0511522   5011385960075   5                    1
171-1046037-0511522   5011385960075   5                    2
```

How can I generate "distict_productcount" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data.groupby('order_number').product_id.nunique()
```

You can get a new column by either using `transform` or `join`

***via `transform`***

```
s = data.groupby('order_number').product_id.transform('nunique')
df = df.assign(distinct_productcount=s)
```

***via `join`***

```
s = data.groupby('order_number').product_id.nunique()
df = df.join(s.rename('distinct_productcount'), on='order_number')
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions like such: data['distinct_product_count'] = 
data.groupby('order_number').product_id.nunique() but the column is empty?

Comment: just checked your solutions. They give the "total_productcount" instead of the distinct one. I am trying this on a larger dataframe with many order_numbers...

Comment: Are you reassigning to the dataframe?  `df = df.assign(distinct_productcount=s)`

Comment: @Jabb for me to be of anymore use, I'll need to see sample data.

Comment: how could I get that data to you? SO seems not the right place.. is email fine?

Comment: @Jabb you only need enough data to demonstrate the point.  You can paste a 50 lines of data to your post with no problem.  SO is totally the right place.  However, if you were so inclined, people use pastebin a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139571/discussion-between-jabb-and-pirsquared).

Comment: your solution worked fine. it was indeed due to messed up data that this did not work in the first instance. thanks!